# how to bring layer on top of another layer in leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

my leaflet map has two layer: 1. temperature, 2. Wind-global 
i want to bring layer 2 to top but my below code in javascript didn't work

```
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, {
            "temperature": bandsWindLayer,
        }).addTo(map);

$.getJSON('wind-global.json', function (data) {

            var velocityLayer = L.velocityLayer({
                displayValues: true,
                displayOptions: {
                    velocityType: 'Global Wind',
                    displayPosition: 'bottomleft',
                    displayEmptyString: 'No wind data'
                },
                data: data,
                maxVelocity: 15
            });
            layerControl.addOverlay(velocityLayer, 'Wind-Global');

        })
map.on("overlayadd", function (event) {
            velocityLayer.bringToFront()
            bandsWindLayer.bringToBack()

        });
```

my error message is "velocityLayer is not defined"

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: @IvanSanchez  can you explain a bit

Comment: Your question is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're having a z-index ordering problem, you thought you could solve it by applying `bringToFront` dynamically, you're asking about that instead of asking "how do I *set up* leaflet layers so that they *always* display in a consistent z-index order"? And the answer to that is "leverage map panes".